# An `Index was outside the bounds of the array` error occurs when I try to access query results

Tags: c#

[As what the title say.... This pops up whenever I try to click Login. Just 
[image]

I also have another system with the same one but it doesn't have an error like this and right now I'm too blind to search for what's wrong XDD

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=
    |DataDirectory|\MMG.mdb";
    string cmdText = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Accounts WHERE User_name=? AND Pass_word=?");
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UName", txtUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PWord", txtPassword.Text);
        DataTable dt = db.execQuery("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE User_name='" + txtUserName.Text + "' AND Pass_word='" + txtPassword.Text + "'");

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString() == "Manager")
            {
                this.Hide();
                frmMainForm mnf = new frmMainForm();
                mnf.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString() == "Cashier")
            {
                this.Hide();
                Sales mnf = new Sales();
                mnf.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the solution in advance ! :)

Comment: do a Rows.Length and Rows[0].Length and you will know what went wrong

Comment: Can I use `'; DROP TABLE Accounts;--` as a password? You should *really* check that there are any results before trying to access them. You have far, far bigger problems though as your code allows hacking your application in seconds

Comment: I'm betting on the 5 on `dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[5]`

Comment: You're essentially trying to reference something that doesn't exist in an array. The suspicious part of the code to me looks like `dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString()` Have you tried debugging to see how many items you have in your array? Don't forget that arrays are `0 based` indexes ;)

Comment: I smell a delicious site to practice my injection skills.

Comment: I suggest dropping all this code and using .NET's built-in authentication mechanisms. They work, they are tested, they allow integration with external providers like Facebook and two-factor authentication.

Comment: @Steve I refer to the *new* mechanisms. It's *not* hard to integrate the old ones either. Definitely easier than trying to recreate them.

Comment: @Sam - Top tip for future - your error is being good to you and telling you the file *and* line number ;)

Comment: @Steve *Identity* is not tied to MVC5. And it does get updated through NuGet regularly

Comment: @Steve - AFAIK, OWIN isn't outdated is it? I though it's more of a standard authentication practice in .NET nowadays?

Comment: that might be a confusion since ItemArray is zero based and you're trying to get the 5th element which is actually index 4.

Comment: ` if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString() == "Manager") { ... } else if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString() == "Cashier") { ... } } ` GOT IT GUYS XD I forgot I deleted a column on my database. Thank you for the hints! <3

Comment: @Sam Go read the linked duplicate, it has an excellent explanation on how to resolve this issue on your own. Don't be lazy, learn how to do this yourself.

Comment: @DavidG I already did fixed it! :) I forgot I deleted a column on my database. Thanks anyway! ^^

Answer (score 1):

You need a check for ItemArray:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   if(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.Length > 5)
   {
      // YOUR CODE
   }
}
```

Comment: should be >5 really

Comment: you should also check if dt.Rows[0] != null and Rows[0].ItemArray != null

Comment: `  if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString() == "Manager")
                        {
                           
                           ...
                        }
                        else if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString() == "Cashier")
                        {
                           ...
                        }

                    } `


GOT IT GUYS XD I forgot I deleted a column on my database. Thank you for the hints! <3